# Error, missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed while running ZIBPPCA

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to inspect data using a new package ZIBPPCA (equivalent to PCA for Zero-inflated data). More for data exploration than dimension reduction.

But I get the error

> Error in while ((difllike > pres) && (i <= maxit)) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" (see code example below).

A regular PCA would be suboptimal because my data has a lot of zeros.

Does anyone have any experience with this sort of problem or with running this function? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```r
library(styler)

library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)
# install_github("khellton/zibppca")
library(devtools)
#> Loading required package: usethis
library(zibppca)


setwd("C:/Users/")

All.SCL.TL <- read.csv("C:/Users/All.SCL.TL.csv")
# remove col X
All.SCL.TL$X <- NULL
#check data structure
str(All.SCL.TL)
#> 'data.frame':    215 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ L   : num  23.1 20.6 24.2 26.8 23.7 ...
#>  $ BPAT: num  45.4 41.5 42.7 43.3 47.5 ...
#>  $ FLT : num  50.9 47 50.7 49.7 50.4 ...
#>  $ dBPT: num  12.79 8.69 0 6.37 14.43 ...
#>  $ tBP : int  1 1 0 2 2 1 3 0 2 0 ...



#check for NA values
colSums(is.na(All.SCL.TL))
#>    L BPAT  FLT dBPT  tBP 
#>    0    0    0    0    0
#no NA values in dataframe

#generate PCA
pcaSCL.TL <- zibppca(All.SCL.TL, scale. = TRUE)
#> [1] "Analyzing data with 5 variables and 215 observations"
#> Error in while ((difllike > pres) && (i <= maxit)) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info  --------------------------------------------------------------
#>  hash: superhero: light skin tone, pencil, vulcan salute: medium skin tone
#> 
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  English_United Kingdom.1252
#>  ctype    English_United Kingdom.1252
#>  tz       Africa/Johannesburg
#>  date     2021-11-17
#>  pandoc   2.14.0.3 @ C:/R/RStudio/bin/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version    date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat    0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  backports     1.3.0      2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  broom         0.7.10     2021-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  cachem        1.0.6      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  callr         3.7.0      2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  cellranger    1.1.0      2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  cli           3.1.0      2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  colorspace    2.0-2      2021-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  crayon        1.4.2      2021-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  DBI           1.1.1      2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  dbplyr        2.1.1      2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  desc          1.4.0      2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  devtools    * 2.4.2      2021-06-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  digest        0.6.28     2021-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.7      2021-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  evaluate      0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fansi         0.5.0      2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0      2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  forcats     * 0.5.1      2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fs            1.5.0      2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  generics      0.1.1      2021-10-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.5      2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  glue          1.4.2      2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  gtable        0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  haven         2.4.3      2021-08-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  highr         0.9        2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  hms           1.1.1      2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2      2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  httr          1.4.2      2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  jsonlite      1.7.2      2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  knitr         1.36       2021-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.1      2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  lubridate     1.8.0      2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  magrittr      2.0.1      2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  memoise       2.0.0      2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  modelr        0.1.8      2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  munsell       0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  pillar        1.6.4      2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  pkgbuild      1.2.0      2020-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  pkgload       1.2.3      2021-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1      2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  processx      3.5.2      2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  ps            1.6.0      2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R.cache       0.15.0     2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R.methodsS3   1.8.1      2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R.oo          1.24.0     2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R.utils       2.11.0     2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R6            2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.7      2021-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  readr       * 2.0.2      2021-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  readxl        1.3.1      2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  remotes       2.4.1      2021-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  reprex      * 2.0.1      2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rlang         0.4.12     2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rmarkdown     2.11       2021-09-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rprojroot     2.0.2      2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13       2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rvest         1.0.2      2021-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  scales        1.1.1      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.1      2021-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringi       1.7.5      2021-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  stringr     * 1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  styler      * 1.6.2      2021-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  testthat      3.1.0      2021-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tibble      * 3.1.5      2021-09-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tidyr       * 1.1.4      2021-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.1      2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tidyverse   * 1.3.1      2021-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tzdb          0.2.0      2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  usethis     * 2.1.3      2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  utf8          1.2.2      2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  vctrs         0.3.8      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  withr         2.4.2      2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  xfun          0.27       2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  xml2          1.3.2      2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  yaml          2.2.1      2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  zibppca     * 0.0.0.9000 2021-11-17 [1] Github (khellton/zibppca@595c1f8)
#> 
#>  [1] C:/R/R-4.1.2/library
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/khellton/zibppca) says it is for bivariate **poisson**. Perhaps it doesn't like the non-integers. I suppose you could test that hypothesis by crudely converting to integer and trying again (`All.SCL.TL[] <- lapply(All.SCL.TL, as.integer)`)

Comment: @user20650 Like you said crude, but the function runs. Thank you.

Comment: okay good, so it doesn't like the non-integers. It is probably worth having a think on what is a sensible probably distribution for your data as it is not poisson.You can get stats advice at https://stats.stackexchange.com/